# Basic image upload in Joomla custom component

Tags: php, image, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to add image upload function to my view where I am creating model. I tried many sample codes here but I can't get to full path to file. My code looks like this:

```
public function submit() {
    jimport ( 'joomla.filesystem.file' );
    // Check for request forgeries.
    JRequest::checkToken () or jexit ( JText::_ ( 'JINVALID_TOKEN' ) );

    // Initialise variables.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication ();
    $model = $this->getModel ( 'createaction' );

    // Get the data from the form POST
    $data = JRequest::getVar ( 'jform', array (), 'post', 'array' );

    echo $data['image'];   <-- here

    $createdItem = $model->createItem ( $data );
    if ($createdItem) {
        $redirect = JRoute::_ ( 'index.php?option=com_akcehned&view=actions', false );
        $this->setRedirect ( $redirect, "Akce byla vytvořena" );
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Omlouváme se, ale něco se stalo špatně</h2>";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Part of file input in xml:

```
    <field 
        name="image" 
        type="file" 
        description="COM_AKCEHNED_FORM_DESC_CREATEACTION_IMAGE" 
        label="COM_AKCEHNED_FORM_LBL_CREATEACTION_IMAGE" 
        size="10" 
        accept="image/*" />
```

Where I tried to echo file file input I get just name (image_name.jpg and so) but I need fullpath right? I saw examples with ['tmp_name'] but It's not working for me.
I tried code like this:

```
$jinput = $app->input;
$files = $jinput->files->get('jform');
$file = $files['image'];
echo $file;
echo $file['tmp_name'];
```

But it's not working for me either. I just get empty values. Can someone give me working block of code where I get data from other inputs and fullpath to file for upload? It's for joomla 2.5, Thanks

Comment: Can you provide var_dump($_FILES) ?

Comment: When I call echo on it, I get "array(0) { }" but I choose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the the form tag contains **enctype** attribute and that it is set to "**multipart/form-data**" if your are going to upload files.

eg

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also see: [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: I am so stupid. I have tag enctype in my view but I was adding it to input for file. Now when I added it to form tag it's much better and I get right results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [DPAttachments](http://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpattachments), it takes only three lines of code to integrate attachment support into your component.

```
if (JLoader::import('components.com_dpattachments.libraries.dpattachments.core', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR)) {
    echo DPAttachmentsCore::render('com_demo.item', $object->id);
}
```

Drag and drop and copy paste from your clipboard (no need to save the file to your hard disk) is supported. Perhaps you want to give it a try. If not here is a link to the Github repo how the upload function is implemented:
https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPAttachments/blob/master/com_dpattachments/admin/models/attachment.php#L50

[I'm the author of this component]